# Is it possible to programmatically slot elements in web components?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, html-templates

Is it possible to automatically or programmatically slot nested web components or elements of a specific type without having to specify the `slot` attribute on them?

Consider some structure like this:

```html
<parent-element>
  <child-element>Child 1</child-element>
  <child-element>Child 2</child-element>

  <p>Content</p>
</parent-element>
```

With the `<parent-element>` having a Shadow DOM like this:

```html
<div id="child-elements">
  <slot name="child-elements">
    <child-element>Default child</child-element>
  </slot>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

The expected result is:

```html
<parent-element>
  <#shadow-root>
    <div id="child-elements">
      <slot name="child-elements">
        <child-element>Child 1</child-element>
        <child-element>Child 2</child-element>
      </slot>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <slot>
        <p>Content</p>
      </slot>
    </div>
</parent-element>
```

In words, I want to enforce that `<child-element>`s are only allowed within a `<parent-element>` similar to `<td>` elements only being allowed within a `<tr>` element. And I want them to be placed within the `<slot name="child-elements">` element. Having to specify a `slot` attribute on each of them to place them within a specific slot of the `<parent-element>` seems redundant.
At the same time, the rest of the content within the `<parent-element>` should automatically be slotted into the second `<slot>` element.

I've first searched for a way to define this when registering the parent element, though [`CustomElementRegistry.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) currently only supports `extends` as option.

Then I thought, maybe there's a function allowing to slot the elements manually, i.e. something like `childElement.slot('child-elements')`, but that doesn't seem to exist.

I've then tried to achive this programmatically in the constructor of the parent element like this:

```js
constructor() {
  super();

  this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

  const childElements = this.getElementsByTagName('child-element');
  const childElementSlot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('[name="child-elements"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
    childElementSlot.appendChild(childElements[i]);
  }
}
```

Though this doesn't move the child elements to the `<slot name="child-elements">`, so all of them still get slotted in the second `<slot>` element.

Comment: I think this has potential to be a good question but in its current form it's a little confusing what you're trying to achieve and what you've managed to achieve so far. Please can you edit / rewrite your question for clarity - I love WebComponents and I'd like to help you with this.

Comment: @Rounin, think ``slotchange`` event for your answer...

Comment: @Rounin I've extended my answer to clarify what's the expected outcome and what I've tried so far.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman As far as I can see, the `slotchange` event is only fired on the `<slot>` element once an element got added or removed from it, but I don't see yet how that helps to let me put them into the correct slot.

Comment: I presume you mean ``childEements[i]`` instead of ``tabs[i]``??? In which case you are no longer using ``SLOT`` technology, because you now **move** *lightDOM* content to *shadowDOM*

Comment: Oops! Of course I meant `childElements[i]`. I've generalized the code for SO. Well, as I wrote, I want to slot them though I didn't find a proper way so far besides moving them from Light DOM to Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your **unnamed** default `<slot></slot>` will capture all elements not assigned to a **named** slot;
so a `slotchange` Event can capture those and force `child-element` into the correct slot:

```js
customElements.define('parent-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("slotchange", (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.name == "") {// <slot></slot> captures
          [...evt.target.assignedElements()]
            .filter(el => el.nodeName == 'CHILD-ELEMENT') //process child-elements
            .map(el => el.slot = "child-elements"); // force them to their own slot
        } else console.log(`SLOT: ${evt.target.name} got:`,evt.target.assignedNodes())
      })}});
customElements.define('child-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(parent = this.closest("parent-element")) {
      // or check and force slot name here
      if (this.parentNode != parent) {
        if (parent) parent.append(this); // Child 3 !!!
        else console.error(this.innerHTML, "wants a PARENT-ELEMENT!");
      }}});
```

```css
child-element { color: red; display: block; } /* style lightDOM in global CSS! */
```

```html
<template id=PARENT-ELEMENT>
  <style>
    :host { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid red; }
    ::slotted(child-element) { background: lightgreen }
    div { border:3px dashed rebeccapurple }
  </style>
  <div><slot name=child-elements></slot></div>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<parent-element>
  <child-element>Child 1</child-element>
  <child-element>Child 2</child-element>
  <b>Content</b>
  <div><child-element>Child 3 !!!</child-element></div>
</parent-element>
<child-element>Child 4 !!!</child-element>
```

Note the logic for processing `<child-element>` not being a **direct** child of `<parent-element>`, you probably want to rewrite this to your own needs

Comment: That works perfectly. I was just wondering why you have to react to the `slotchange` event and can't proactively move them to `<slot name="child-elements">`, i.e. when they get created or upgraded or before they are slotted.

Comment: Yes, you can do without the slotchange Event and and put the logic on the child-element: if slot is **not** correct,set it

Comment: Also [`connectedCallback()` doesn't take parameters](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#upgrades), so `parent = this.closest("parent-element")` should be defined within the function body.

Comment: No, you can declare variables there.. this is valid JavaScript, we are not limited by TypeScript syntax.. If components should be small, that is a create place to prevent LET statements.. saves 4 bytes. See the svg() method in my [IconMeister](https://github.com/iconmeister/iconmeister.github.io/blob/master/elements.iconmeister.js) all "variables" are "parameters"

Comment: It _is_ valid JavaScript and it saves a few bytes on network transfer, yes, but what I meant is that the DOM specification says `connectedCallback()` is called without parameters. Placing it within the parameters list might let people reading your answer think that they can somehow change `parent`. So doing it may be good when you want to minimize your code but for clarity here on SO it's better to use a `const` statement here.

Comment: assigning `el.slot` doesn't seem to work if the node is Text... is there a way to re-assign the slot of text node?

Comment: @Michael, ask as question, I can't paste code in comments

Answer (score 1):

As of recently, yes, you can, by using the [`assign()` method of slot elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assign). Sadly, Safari doesn't support it yet, but there is [a polyfill](https://github.com/jsxtools/dom-slot-assign).

Comment: I didn't try it out yet but it looks like that solves the issue. The downside of this approach, though, seems to be that you can't mix automatic slot assignment with manual assignment (yet). In my example, it would be best if I could define that all `<child-element>`s are slotted manually but the rest automatically in the unnamed `<slot>`.